# Why was Stalin OK with the UN's headquaters being placed in the US?

Tags: soviet-union, stalin, united-nations

It feels like Stalin should have objected to this because this gives the US some extra influence. Why not insist on placing the headquaters somewhere more neutral?

Comment: I don't think he was asked. The US set it up and everyone else went along with it and Stalin could choose between staying out or coming in.

Comment: Stalin was thrilled because it gave his spies in NYC extra cover.

Comment: The decision to host the UN in the US was made in December 1945, it was then a question of which city. The Soviet Union did veto Boston, but obviously not New York. [History of the United Nations - Facilities - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_United_Nations#Facilities): *Potential sites for the UN Headquarters included Vienna, Switzerland, Berlin, Quebec, and the Netherlands before **the delegation decided on a headquarters in the United States by December 1945**.*

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: What basic research have you done on the United Nations agreements?

Comment: @MarkOlson that's completely ridiculous claim. Without the USSR there would be no UN, all the headquarters definitely were agreed upon. P.S. Why this awful comment was so upvoted?

Comment: To the OP: The UN has a backup headquarters in Switzerland, by the way.